# Is there a better way to remove all other code except Function_ node using PHP Parser?

Tags: php, parsing

New to PHP here. I am using PHP-Parser by [nikic](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser).

I would like to remove all nodes that are not type `Node\Stmt\Function_`.

I currently can do this via this code:

```
$traverser = new NodeTraverser();
$traverser->addVisitor(new class extends NodeVisitorAbstract {
    
    // To leave functions alone
    public function enterNode(Node $node) {
        if ($node instanceof Node\Stmt\Function_) {
            return NodeTraverser::DONT_TRAVERSE_CHILDREN;
        }
    }

    // To remove any other nodes that are not 'Function_' type
    // Currently can only remove 'If', 'For' and 'Expression' types
    public function leaveNode(Node $node) {
        if ($node instanceof Node\Stmt\If_ || 
        $node instanceof Node\Stmt\For_ || 
        $node instanceof Node\Stmt\Expression) {
            return NodeTraverser::REMOVE_NODE;
        }
    }
});
```

But this will result in a huge `if(...||)` statement carrying all the different node types. I tried using  `if(!$node instanceof Node\Stmt\Function_)` shown below, but it will result in error. I tried  `if(!($node instanceof Node\Stmt\Function_))` also have the same error.

```
public function leaveNode(Node $node) {
    if (!$node instanceof Node\Stmt\Function_) {
        return NodeTraverser::REMOVE_NODE;
    }
}
```

#ERROR:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught LogicException: leaveNode() returned invalid value of type integer in /usr/local/bin/vendor/nikic/php-parser/lib/PhpParser/NodeTraverser.php:168
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/local/bin/vendor/nikic/php-parser/lib/PhpParser/NodeTraverser.php(146): PhpParser\NodeTraverser->traverseNode()
#1 /usr/local/bin/vendor/nikic/php-parser/lib/PhpParser/NodeTraverser.php(223): PhpParser\NodeTraverser->traverseNode()
#2 /usr/local/bin/vendor/nikic/php-parser/lib/PhpParser/NodeTraverser.php(91): PhpParser\NodeTraverser->traverseArray()
#3 /home/test/Desktop/test.php(130): PhpParser\NodeTraverser->traverse()
#4 {main}
  thrown in /usr/local/bin/vendor/nikic/php-parser/lib/PhpParser/NodeTraverser.php on line 168
```

I understand that remove node can only be implemented in leaveNode. Hence, I was thinking if there is a better way to do this instead of chunking huge If statement to match every single type other than 'Function_'?

Thanks!

**[Edit] Let me try to share more about the bigger picture and expected input and output.**

Big picture: I would like to build a program that when given a PHP code, can retrieve specific nodes (e.g. case, function, loops) upon request. For this case, it is Function nodes. To do this, I am using Parser at the moment. I may explore using tokenization in the future if this does not work.

Input: a sample piece of PHP code like below.

```
function writeMsg() {
  echo "Hello world!";
}

writeMsg(); 

$x = 5;

if ($x = 5) {
  echo "x is 5";
} else {
  echo "Something is wrong";
}
```

If user wants to retrieve function nodes, output will be just the function with its content, and nothing else:

```
function writeMsg()
{
    echo "Hello world!";
}
```

If user wants to retrieve the If statement, output will be:

```
if ($x = 5) {
    echo "x is 5";
} else {
    echo "Something is wrong";
}
```

Big picture will be to retrieve any type of nodes that the user specified. However, for now, function will do.

Comment: What do you want to achieve out of this, if you want a list of these specific nodes, then it may be easier to extract them rather than remove all others.  It may be objecting to that removing nodes in these cases would end up with invalid code as so doesn't allow it.

Comment: @NigelRen Hmm, good thinking. Do you have an idea on how to extract Function_ nodes other than using leaveNode to remove the rest?

Comment: What do you need from the function nodes, not sure if standalone they actually make sense.  Do you want the details of the function?

Comment: @NigelRen Sorry that I did not explain this properly. The function nodes are to be further analyzed for another project. The function nodes and function details should remain untouched. For example, function {...} content within the curly brackets should all be untouched. The bigger picture will be to create a program that can extract specific nodes (e.g. function, class, loops etc.) from a piece of php code. Hence, I thought of going about this using parser. I am also thinking about tokenization but wanted to try parser first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As another solution, this extracts the functions from the AST as it finds them. This is also able to extract functions in classes (using `instanceof Node\Stmt\ClassMethod`) as well as nested functions...

```
$traverser = new NodeTraverser();
class FunctionExtract extends NodeVisitorAbstract {
    // List of functions
    public $functionList = [];

    public function enterNode(Node $node) {
        if ($node instanceof Node\Stmt\Function_
                || $node instanceof Node\Stmt\ClassMethod ) {
            $this->functionList[] = $node;
            return NodeTraverser::DONT_TRAVERSE_CHILDREN;
        }
    }
}
$extract = new FunctionExtract();
$traverser->addVisitor($extract);
$traverser->traverse($ast);

$prettyPrinter = new PhpParser\PrettyPrinter\Standard;
$newCode = $prettyPrinter->prettyPrintFile($extract->functionList);

echo $newCode;
```

Answer (score 1):

After some experimentation, I found that using the node traversal method could work, but it couldn't remove statements in the base of the code.

So with code like...

```
<?php
if ( $a == 1) return;
$b=1;
function test2(string $a): int {
    $c = 1;
    if ($c == 2) {
        $c = 1;
    }
    return 2;
}
```

Using...

```
$traverser = new NodeTraverser();
$traverser->addVisitor(new class extends NodeVisitorAbstract {
    public function enterNode(Node $node) {
        if ($node instanceof Node\Stmt\Function_
                || $node instanceof Node\Stmt\If_ ) {
            return NodeTraverser::DONT_TRAVERSE_CHILDREN;
        }
    }

    public function leaveNode(Node $node) {
        if ($node instanceof Node\Stmt &&
                ! $node instanceof Node\Stmt\Function_ &&
                ! $node instanceof Node\Stmt\InlineHTML &&
                ! $node instanceof Node\Stmt\Class_) {
            return NodeTraverser::REMOVE_NODE;
        }
    }
});
```

produces

```
<?php 
if ($a == 1) {
}
$b = 1;
function test2(string $a) : int
{
    $c = 1;
    if ($c == 2) {
        $c = 1;
    }
    return 2;
}
```

So only the `return` under the first `if` is removed.

Note that I use `$node instanceof Node\Stmt` to say it's a statement type node, and then only say to leave `! $node instanceof Node\Stmt\Function_` nodes.

So changing to make a simple pass of the original AST array and copy anything that is a function...

```
$newAst = [];
foreach ( $ast as $node )   {
    if ($node instanceof Node\Stmt\Function_) {
        $newAst[] = $node;
    }
}
$prettyPrinter = new PhpParser\PrettyPrinter\Standard;
$newCode = $prettyPrinter->prettyPrintFile($newAst);

echo $newCode;
```

gives out...

```
<?php

function test2(string $a) : int
{
    $c = 1;
    if ($c == 2) {
        $c = 1;
    }
    return 2;
}
```

If you just wanted the function signatures, you could also reset the statements when copying...

```
    $node->stmts = [];
    $newAst[] = $node;
```

and you would end up with...

```
<?php

function test2(string $a) : int
{
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why but when I use `$node instanceof Node\Stmt && ! $node instanceof Node\Stmt\Function_`, it will give me the error again. May I ask what version of Php-parser are you using? I am using v4.10.4.

Comment: @SweeterWeather, what is the error?  It may also help if you can add the code (as specific as possible) causing the problem to the question.

Comment: It sounds like the specific code you are processing, does the same happen with the example code I've used in my answer.

Comment: The error is the same as the one I've wrote in the original question. It is caused by the leaveNode LogicException. Anyway, with the simple pass of the AST array, we would not even need traversal anymore. Pretty neat! I've tried the solution and it works for functions that are not nested in other nodes (i.e. functions declaration in a class would not work), but overall it is a pretty good solution. Thanks!

Comment: @SweeterWeather, I've added a few more exceptions to the classes processed, it excludes `if` and `class` statements and seems to work a bit more.

Comment: is there a particular reason to exclude `if` in the `enterNode` ? I found out that if the input code contains an `if...else..` statement, and if `enterNode` does not exclude `if`, then the `leaveNode LogicException` error will be reproduced.

Comment: @SweeterWeather, most likely that removing the `if` before looking at the `else` could mean that you will remove it and leave a dangling `else`.

Comment: I see.. That make sense. Thanks so much for your help!